# When PlotRangePadding is provided with Scaled[] and the lower limit is non-negative, xmin for the tick mark function is wrong

Tags: plotting, bugs

For things like `Plot`, tick marks can be provided as a function (see [Ticks](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html)), which will be given the values of the minimum and maximum ends of the respective axis or frame side, with `PlotRangePadding` taken into account.

For example,

```
foo[xmin_, xmax_] := (Print[{xmin, xmax}]; Automatic);
Plot[
  10 x,
  {x, -10, 10},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameTicks -> {{foo, None}, {foo, None}},
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotRangePadding -> {1, 1}
]
```

You can see that the `min` and `max` are given to us correctly, as expected:

[image: Plot of 10x]

I could use `PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[0], Scaled[0]}`. The result is still as expected:

[image: Plot of 10x]

Now, if the left limit is `0`:

```
foo[xmin_, xmax_] := (Print[{xmin, xmax}]; Automatic);
Plot[
  10 x,
  {x, 0, 10},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameTicks -> {{foo, None}, {foo, None}},
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[0], Scaled[0]}
]
```

I get this:

[image: Plot of 10x]

The resulting plot is correct, but the given value of the minimum end of each frame side is not. This happens whenever the left limit (i.e., the `xmin` in `{x, xmin, xmax}`) is not negative.

Of course I can work around this issue by offsetting `xmin` in `foo` accordingly.

Could you please confirm if this is a bug? Mathematica 11.3 on macOS High Sierra here.

Comment: Why do you need the `xmin` value? Perhaps there is an alternate way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: @CarlWoll I need to customise the length of the ticks, for which there is no direct option. Yes there are many possible alternative ways and I'm implementing one of them. It would be nice to know though if the issue is really a bug.

Comment: So, you're `foo` function will create ticks with longer tick lengths (i.e., larger values for the third argument of a tick spec?) If so, I think you're only seeing preprocessing of ticks by `Plot`, but the actual ticks don't change, and the correct `xmin` will be used when the plot is rendered.

Comment: @CarlWoll Yes, that's what `foo` does (and yes, with the third argument of a tick spec). I don't understand what you're trying to say afterwards. Note though that the 'wrong' `xmin` is only given when `PlotRangePadding` is provided with `Scaled[]` (as opposed to coordinate units).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot) is not doing the right thing here. As a workaround, instead of including the [`FrameTicks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks) in the [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot) call, you can use [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show) to add it afterwards:

```
foo[xmin_,xmax_] := (Print[{xmin, xmax}]; {{xmin, Defer["xmin"=xmin]},{xmax,Defer["xmax"==xmax]}});
p = Show[
    Plot[10 x, {x,0,10},
        Frame->True, PlotRange->All, PlotRangePadding->{Scaled[0],Scaled[0]}
    ],
    FrameTicks->{{foo, None}, {foo, None}}
]
```

[image]

The correct `xmin` and `xmax` values are generated, and if you check your messages window, you will also see the correct `xmin` and `xmax` coordinates printed there.

Comment: Thank you. Should I add the 'bugs' tag?

Comment: @Taiki I think adding the bugs tag is fine, but more important would be to report it to support.

Comment: OK. Will do as soon as I can.